# Can't upload an image using Objective-C and PHP

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xcode

Good morning,

I have tried a lot of things but I still can't show the name of the file uploaded using Objective-C and PHP, the name is "filename". I don't know what am I doing wrong but I need your help because I have followed a lot of tutorials and I still can't output the name of the file.

I have access to "upload.php" and it's fine but I can't make this work.

What I have to do to make this work? Any help will be much appreciated.

Here is my xcode code:

```
- (IBAction)uploadPhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSString *imageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data;    name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", _imageView];



    //NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imageView, 0.4);

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imageView.image, 90);

    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.website.com/upload.php";



    NSLog(@"upload url %@", urlString);



    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"--------------------------    -14737809831466499882746641449";

    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data;     boundary=%@",boundary];

    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];



    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary]     dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:imageString ]     dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/object-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary]     dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];



    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



    //NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", returnString);
```

And that´s my PHP:

```
    <?php
    $uploaddir = '/imagenes/';
    $file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['name'], $uploadfile)) {
            echo "transfer successful at: http://www.mywebsite.com/{$uploaddir}/{$file}";
    }

echo "File: ".$file;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any errors at all?

Comment: No @JayBlanchard , just the output "File: " without any content.

Comment: Your posted PHP code doesn't appear to be receiving data; it's just dealing with a local file rename. Is there data received by your server? If there is, I'm guessing there's something wrong with your PHP configuration.

Comment: How can I check if I'm recieving data by my server? Thanks in advance @IanMacDonald, I'm posting from another account because I can't remember de password e-mail. Regards.